# Retain state in react chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Running react-app in chrome does not retain state. For example I have a timer app. Timer runs, but after closing the popup it does not retain the state.

What is the proper course of action to run a background script with react-app? How to achieve it?

Example code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"

const Timer = () => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let interval;
        if (isActive) {
             interval = setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds + 1), 1000)
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        //stops the interval from running
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [seconds, isActive]);

    const toggleActive = () => {
         setIsActive(!isActive)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={toggleActive}>{seconds}</button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Timer
```

Comment: The popup is a page and hence like any other page it exists only when shown. When the popup is closed its scripts don't run. To save the state you can use any storage like `localStorage` or `chrome.storage.local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to keep the timer running even though the popup is not open anymore. And currently you start the timer in the page of the popup (which would stop running once it's closed).

You could run the timer in a background script directly. That one would keep running even if you don't have a popup open.
You need to register it in the manifest of your extension like this:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest

To communicate with your popup so you can show the progress of the timer you could use one of the messaging options that for extensions:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Another approach could also be to store the start of your timer so you can start up the timer again when you re-open the popup. This could look something like this:

on popup start, check if start time is already set and maybe start timer:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['start'], function(result) {
  if(result.start) {
    // restart the timer
  }
});
```

on clicking start, store the start time and start timer:

```
const now = Date.now();
chrome.storage.local.set({start: now}, function() {
  // start timer
});
```

and when you click stop, remove the start time from storage:

```
chrome.storage.local.remove('start', function() {
  // also stop the active timer
});
```

You can find more documentation on the storage for extensions here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Answer (score 0):

If you use redux with redux-persist then store the timer in Redux. No need to save to localStorage.